# nginx 301 redirect to subfolder on primary domain

Tags: nginx, wordpress, rewrite

I just set up Wordpress on my VPS, so far it's the only item on my site. For SEO purposes, I think it's better to redirect the primary domain to the blog folder.

So let's say the primary domain is `example.com` and Wordpress is at `example.com/blog`.
I want to rewrite `www.example.com` and `example.com` to `example.com/blog`.

I Googled and got some scripts and made some changes to my nginx config file. My configuration is:

```
#301 redirect www to non-www
server {
server_name  www.example.com;
location = / {
rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 permanent;
}
}

#301 non-www to subfolder
server {
server_name  example.com;
location = / {
rewrite ^/(.*)  http://example.com/blog$1 permanent;
}
}
```

It works at some degree, it successfully redirects to `example.com/blog`. The only problem is I get a 404 not found error. When I only make nginx redirect `www` to `example.com/blog` I can access the blog page successfully.

I know there is something wrong in the non-www to subfolder script, but do not how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#301 redirect www to non-www
server {
    server_name  www.example.com;
    # redirect all requests
    rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com$1 permanent;
}
server {
    server_name  example.com;
    # this only matches /, and not any other requested file
    location = / {
        rewrite ^ http://example.com/blog/ permanent;
    }

    # rest of configuration goes here...
}
```

Comment: im really appreciate your help, but still got 404 page not found error. still still is something wrong with redirect non-www to blog folder script.  :(((

Comment: What's the address you're typing that's ending up in a 404?

Comment: got 404 when access http://example.com/blog/. but i fingure out use php script to redirect http://example.com to http://example.com/blog/. and redirect 'www'.example.com' to http://example.com with nginx. in this way, i can access the blog folder, but this is not an efficient way. :((

Comment: A simpler solution is to not use /blog, and host the blog in the domain root.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has **two parts**.

1. Getting the rewrite of the server name.
2. Getting the rewrite to the said directory.

As per 1. your rewrite rule is **incorrect**. There's no need to capture anything, you just pass the variable `$request_uri` that contains the request like the client sends it to Nginx.

```
server {
    server_name  www.example.com;
    # redirect all requests
    rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

For the second part use a much simpler rewrite like this:

```
server {
    server_name  example.com;
    # this only matches /, and not any other requested file
    location = / {
        rewrite ^.+ /blog permanent;
    }
```

```
# rest of configuration goes here...
```

}